# Origin to selected vertex for multiple meshes

Tags: python, scripting

I tried to create a script that allows for a selection of meshes, to make the selected vertex the origin of the mesh.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
```

this is what I did, but it's for a single instance and it doesn't work.

To better understand what I am trying to do, here is a visual representation.

[image: meshes with the origin of the splited mesh]

[image: selected vertex of the meshes]

[image: origin to the selected vertex]

I have a mesh that I split into several meshes and these meshes have the same origin as the original mesh.
I want to make the vertex I select for each mesh the new origin of the mesh.

What I can do manually is:

- Select a mesh
- Switch to edit mode
- Cursor to selected
- Switch back to object mode
- Origin to 3D cursor

but it can be very long if I have a lot of meshes.
So I would like to create a script to do this, unfortunately I don't know enough about programming on blender.

Answer (score 2):

you should apply the new origin to each of the selected objects. Get a list of the selected objects and apply the origin with a for loop.

This is a sample code:

```
C = bpy.context
O = bpy.ops

# get list of selected objects
objs = C.selected_objects

for obj in objs:
    # make current object as active
    C.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    # apply origin
    O.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='MEDIAN')
```

Comment: The loop works but the cursor doesn't snap to the selected vertex location.

Thanks a lot for the help